# use two vectors in R to make a new one

Tags: r, vector

So this is a pretty odd question, but i have two vectors in R:  one is a sequential list of IDs and the other is how many times I want that id to appear in the new vector.

for example:

```
ids: A B C D
times: 4 2 5 3
```

and i want to end up with

```
new: A A A A B B C C C C C D D D
```

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `rep` function as in :

```
> rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), times=c(4, 2, 5, 3))
 [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D" "D"
```

Comment: And just for interest, the inverse function of this process is `rle`, which takes a vector such as A,A,A,A,B,B,C,C and spits out the values and number of repeats.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rep()`

```
> rep(LETTERS[1:4], times = c(4,2,5,3))
 [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D" "D"
```

Answer (score 1):

That certainly makes sense.

```
rep(c("A","B","C","D"),times=c(4,2,5,3))
[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D" "D"
```